# Impossible to delete cookies on Geb & Spock test

Tags: java, cookies, spock, geb

I'm defining some Specs with Geb (0.12.2) and Spock for test my frontend. 
The login system of my application depends on SSO with our internal IDP. Once I go to the private part of my application, if not logged previously in our IDP, it will redirect to the IDP homepage, then login and redirects you again to the initial asked private url.

I need to logout at any time. To accomplish this I can:

- Do a logout.
- Delete cookie seted by idp.

I wish to initiallize every GebSpec class without any previous cookie or state from previous GebSpec execution and don't want to depend on logout system. 
To accomplish this I can:

1. Delete all cookies.
2. Close the browser (don't want to do that).

But I'm having problems with two aproaches.

1) Deleting cookies
As said in http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#implicit-driver-management I've tried to call `clearCookies()` method in `setup()`, `setupSpec()`, `cleanup()` and `cleanupSpec()` methods with no effect on cookies (debugging and inspecting cookies in the browser nothing is deleted after these methods are called).
I'm launching tests from IntelliJ and also from command line calling gradlew.

Also, as said in http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#cookie-management-in-tests:

> The geb.spock.GebSpec class will clear the cookies in the cleanup() method unless the spec is @Stepwise, in which case they are cleared in cleanupSpec() (meaning that all feature methods in a stepwise spec share the same browser state).

That's not happening in my GebSpec classes, nor default nor forcing it.

Am I doing anything is interfering in this suposed default behaviour (not using @Stepwise) or I'm missing anything? Someone is having same effect?

*PS: I was using a BaseGepSpec for defining common setup() methods for all my `GebSpec` classes and tried to not extending with same result. I was also using `GebReportingSpec` and tried without with same effect...)*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Browser.clearCookies()` only clears cookies for the current domain, this is a limitation of how browsers work (you can only control cookies of the current domain in javascript as well) and what [WebDriver does when you call `deleteAllCookies()`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Options.html#deleteAllCookies--). To be fair, there is a [ticket for making the docs clearer about what `Browser.clearCookies()` actually does](https://github.com/geb/issues/issues/159).

To clear cookies for your IDP domain you need to go to any url for that domain first and after that call `clearCookies()`.

Comment: Exoddus, did the option from @erdi work for you. Did you use clearCookies() in setup() or within the definition step.